# "Undefined" on my loop trying to fetch object in json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, undefined

Hi guys I'm having trouble in my for loop because there's a word "undefined" on the result of my loop, I'm trying to fetch objects on my json file and my loop works fine, I'm just wondering on how to remove the "undefined" word in my loop? thanks in advance.
[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdyUL.png)

[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B92kw.png)

[and here is my json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he4ch.png)

Comment: please share you code not snapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, show variable before the loop is undefined, you haven't set some value for it, and using it without value. So, JavaScript can not identify the value of the variable and set it as "undefined"

Comment: Wow it actually work! Didn't notice that! Anyway thank you so much!

Comment: Glad my solution helped you, @JayRhick

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
   var show = "";
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
       var obj = data[i];
       show += "<div>"+obj["id"]+" "+obj["fname"]+"</div>"
   }
   $(".show").html(show)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your `show` variable with an empty string like azizbek mentioned.

```
let show = '';
```

If you don't want to, then use a condition to ignore it like this:

```
if (data[i] && data[i].id) {
    let obj = data[id];
    show += ...
}
```

Note:
I see that you use `var` in places that is not needed, inside a for loop or inside a callback. See [this post](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e) for more info